# Calling Method From SKScene Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm trying to call my newExplosion method (in a touchesBegan method) that is in my Scene class from my ViewController.m class. The problem is that it doesn't add the SKEmitterNode to the View (which is what the newExplosion method is supposed to do). It works when the touchesBegan method is in the Scene class, but not when it is called from my ViewController class.

This is my Scene class:

```
#import "Scene.h"
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@implementation Scene : SKScene

- (void) newExplosion: (float)x : (float) y {
    SKEmitterNode *emitter =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"crouchEffect" ofType:@"sks"]];
    emitter.position = CGPointMake(x,y);
    [self addChild:emitter];
}
// This works VVVV
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self newExplosion:100 :100];
}
```

This is the SpriteKit related stuff in my ViewController.m class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    SKView * skView = _skView;
    SKScene * scene = [Scene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
// Doesn't work VVVV
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    Scene * ss = [[Scene alloc] init];
    [ss newExplosion:100:100];
}
```

I added a debug message in my newExplosion method to see if it was actually running it and it printed it out. So it's being called, but not adding the SKEmitterNode to the view.

Comment: you create a new scene with alloc/init, you need to use self.scene and cast it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new scene everytime you touch the screen, but you never add this to the view,  I think you want to do something like this

```
//In view controller interface add
{
  Scene * _scene;
}

//In implementation, change the following
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    SKView * skView = _skView;
    _scene = [Scene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    _scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [skView presentScene:_scene];
}
// Doesn't work VVVV
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [_scene newExplosion:100:100];
}
```

Comment: Worked great! PS: The SKScene should be Scene (in the implementation).

Comment: Not a problem, I changed it to reflect your comment. Glad it worked out for you